# How to convert decimal value in to color name - C#

Tags: c#

I have color value in decimal format like 32768 the corresponding hexadecimal format is 008000 and the equivalent color name is green. I want to convert the decimal value into the equivalent color name in c#. I saw some code which converts into RGB value. Can anyone tell me how to achieve this in c#?

Comment: What if your color-value is 32769? Not all possible colour-values have a proper name.

Comment: You'd have to define what each name should represent.  You say 008000 is green, but 009900 is also green, just a different shade.

Comment: There are lot's of answers to this question already. Did google not yield any results? Btw.: It's funny how fast obviously wrong answers get posted to simple questions like this only to be downvoted and deleted ... this time they all were the exact same wrong answer.

Comment: @juharr if you put `background: green` on the CSS of some page then convert that color to hex it is going to show as `008000`. There is a list of "Known Colors", which is what the OP is asking.

Comment: @BrunoLM I don't see anything in the question that says why they want to convert it.  If it's to make it more human readable then converting to known names is going to miss a lot of colors.  And if they're converting it to use in CSS as you suppose then that's just silly since you can just use the hex value to begin with.